# Pascal results window

Tags: output, lazarus, freepascal, slowdown

I have written a programme which merges two 1D arrays containing names. I print the list of arr1, arr2 and arr3.

I am using Lazarus Free Pascal v. 1.0.14 . I was wondering if anyone knows how to break the results in the dos-like window because the list is so long that I can only see the last few names in the returned results. The rest go by too fast to read.

I know I can save the resuls to file and I also use the delay command, but would like to know if there is a way to somehow break the results or slow them down or even edit the output console?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Write some lines and then prompt for user interaction. Like `Write('Press [Enter] to continue ...'); ReadLn;`

Comment: Not a bad workaround thanks! Unfortunately, it still gets cut off but is way better than without your suggestion. I may have to export to file after all. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a programming question, because your console application should output the values without pause. Otherwise your program would become useless if you ever wanted it to run as part of another pipeline in an automated fashion.

Instead you need a tool that you wrap around your program to paginate the output if, and when, you so desire. Such tools are known as [terminal pagers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager) and the basic one that ships with Windows is called `more`. You execute your program and pipe the output to the `more` program. Like this:

```
C:\SomeDir>MyProject.exe <input_args> | more
```

Comment: No it itsn't a programming question which is why I did not include any code in the original post. I think you can only pipe stuff when using a unix environment. I am using cmd on Windows. But thank you for your comment.

Comment: Nope. This works just fine on Windows. Windows supports piping, and `cmd` uses the same syntax as *nix. And what I wrote was not a comment, but an answer. It really is the answer to your problem. If you want to get more advanced you can use the GNU tool `less` which is (ironically) like a more advanced version of `more`. Doesn't come with Windows as standard but you can obtain it readily from a variety of places. I use it daily.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the code of your loop in the following way:

say you print the results by the followng loop:

```
for i:=0 to 250 do
  WriteLn(ArrUnited[i]);
```

you can replace it with:

```
for i:=0 to 250 do
  begin
    WriteLn(ArrUnited[i]);
    if (i mod 25) = 24 then //the code will wait for the user pressing Enter every 25 rows
      ReadLn;
  end;
```

For the future please! post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your questions otherwise everyone has to guess what your code is.